# is CLucene is faster than java lucene?

Tags: lucene, clucene

i am using java lucene and i am moving my code from java to c++ for some reason so i need to know about the performance  of clucene
can any one explain

Answer (score 4):

According to a [benchmark](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clucene/index.php?title=Benchmarks) posted on CLucene's SourceForge wiki, CLucene outperforms Java Lucene by a factor of 2 to 3 during indexing, but search performance is only about 10% better.

Comment: Those benchmarks are old enough that it's safe to say they're not relevant at this time. They also quote performance on pretty old hardware. Then again, that may be a good use case for a C version.

Comment: @Ross: Um, yes, the question and answer are over 1.5 years old, and the benchmarks were about that old at the time. And they're relevant as long as you don't have any newer ones with a different result.

Answer (score 1):

The data Michael linked to is quite old and incomplete. The answer is yes mainly because C++ has no GC threads and memory allocations are made in C++ by hand. Even reference counting in C++ will be performed faster in C++ since its compiled to machine code, unlike Java which runs on a VM.

For more info see the free chapter on CLucene from Lucene In Action, available from http://www.code972.com/blog/2010/06/lucene-in-action-free-chapter-coupon-code/

Comment: -1. Dismissing a benchmark (even if old and homegrown) and substituting it for unexplained, unproved, even *debunked* statements of faith shouldn't be the basis for an answer. Even the linked text insists on hearsay and handwaving instead of actually giving any hard data.